# Openlayers can't display GeoJSON Vectorlayer from RestfulAPI (Node)

Tags: node.js, json, openlayers, geojson, koa

I created a restfulAPI using Nodejs, from which I want to create a new Vectorlayer in Openlayers and display on a map.

The GeoJSON I get from the API looks like this (JSONlint and geojson.io both say it's valid):

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [9.9627244, 53.5565378]
        },
        "properties": {
            "f1": 1,
            "f2": "Tabakbörse",
            "f3": "Beim Grünen Jäger 2, 20359 Hamburg"
        }
    }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [9.9874951, 53.5162912]
        },
        "properties": {
            "f1": 2,
            "f2": "Fähr Getränke Kiosk",
            "f3": "Veringstraße 27, 21107 Hamburg"
        }
    }]
}
```

The function addKioskGeoJSON should add the layer to the map:

```
import './map.scss'
import {Map as olMap} from 'ol'
import View from 'ol/View'
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile'
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM'
import { fromLonLat } from 'ol/proj'
import {Style, Icon} from 'ol/style'
import { Vector as layerVector } from 'ol/layer'
import { Vector as sourceVector } from 'ol/source/'
import GeoJSON from 'ol/format/GeoJSON'


import { Component } from '../component'


const template = '<div ref="mapContainer" class="map-container"></div>'

export class Map extends Component {
  constructor (placeholderId, props) {
    super(placeholderId, props, template)

    const target = this.refs.mapContainer

    // Initialize Openlayers Map
    this.map = new olMap({
       ....
      });

    this.layers = {}; // Map layer dict (key/value = title/layer)
  }

  addKioskGeojson (geojson) {
    console.log(geojson)
    this.layers.kiosks = new layerVector({
      title: 'Kiosks',
      visible: true,
      source: new sourceVector({
        format: new GeoJSON(),
        projection : 'EPSG:4326',
        url: geojson
      }),
      style: new Style({
        image: new Icon(({
          anchor: [0.5, 40],
          anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
          anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
          src: './map-icons/kiosk.png'
        }))
      })
    });
    this.map.addLayer(this.layers.kiosks)
  }
}
```

What's weird is, that I can console.log() the geojson as you can see in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o97Du.png) and my code, but get an 404 error message for adding it as an vector layer.

Comment: Your GET request looks wrong. How do you call `addKioskGeojson`? Edit: Contains `geojson` the URL or the features? If last, than `url: geojson` is wrong and should possibly be `features: geojson`.

Comment: I get the data from Postgres, then use this middlerware: `// Add GeoJSON endpoint from kiosks table
router.get('/kiosks', async ctx => {
  const results = await database.getKiosks()
  if (results.length === 0) { ctx.throw(404) } // 404 for no results
  ctx.body = results
})` and call the `addKioskGeojson` from my main.js file: `  /** Load map data from the API */
  async loadMapData () {
    // Download kiosk pois
    const kioskGeojson = await this.api.getKiosks()
    // Add data to map
    this.mapComponent.addKioskGeojson(kioskGeojson)`

Comment: When i try `features: geojson` I get this error: `TypeError: collection.getArray is not a function`. `geojson` contains the features

Comment: A geojson defines features, but to obtain the features as OpenLayers objects the geojson must be parsed using `readFeatures`

Answer (score 0):

You already have a geojson object (it's not a url).  All you need to do is parse the features from the object:

```
  addKioskGeojson (geojson) {
    console.log(geojson)
    this.layers.kiosks = new layerVector({
      title: 'Kiosks',
      visible: true,
      source: new sourceVector({
        features: new GeoJSON().readFeatures(geojson, { featureProjection: this.map.getView().getProjection() })
      }),
      style: new Style({
        image: new Icon(({
          anchor: [0.5, 40],
          anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
          anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
          src: './map-icons/kiosk.png'
        }))
      })
    });
    this.map.addLayer(this.layers.kiosks)
  }
```